# castle windsor startable-facility | pass parameters to the start method

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to use a component that requires a start method be called after the object is constructed. I tried using the startable facility for castle for this but the start method in this component takes some arguments. Is there a way I can supply arguments to the method called by the startable facility in castle? Or is there another way of doing this (short of calling the method myself)?
I cannot modify the component I am using.

Comment: Wrap the component with an IStartable and inject the necessary arguments to wrapper constructor?

Comment: Sure. That is what I will do. Was wondering if castle provides something out of the box to do this that I am not aware of.

Comment: In this particular case, I figured the component did not need to be a startable after all and a simple OnCreate(k, I => ...) did the job for me. I guess even for  a startable, simply combining .start().OnCreate(k, I => ...) should do the same thing.